# Generalization of the Identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I was wondering what can be said about two complex functions that are very close on a domain?

For example let, f,g be two analytic function with $|f-g| = O(e^{-X})$ on the real interval $(X, 2X],$ where $X$ is a large number.

Could we say that they are equal or almost equal on a large domain in $\mathbb{C}$ containing the interval? Basically is it true to concluse that $g(z)=f(z)+ ce^{-z}$ on $\Re(z)> X$?

The identity theorem says that if two analytic complex functions are equal on a set with an accumulation point then they are equal everywhere else in the domain. The proof uses their Taylor expansion around the accumulation point.

Edit: After Jose's answer I realized that I need to consider a domian with bound hight, so we are looking at $\Re(z)> X, \Im(z) \ll 1.$

Comment: $f(z) = 0$ and $g(z) = \exp(-z^2)$ is a simple counterexample.

Comment: You are correct, I should have said $f=g$ in a region with bounded height.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\bigl|\sin(x)e^{-x}-0\bigr|=O(e^{-x})$ on $(x,2x]$. On the other hand, the restriction of $\sin(z)e^{-z}$ to any vertical line is unbounded. Therefore, you certainly don't have $\sin(z)e^{-z}=0+e^{-z}$ on any half-plane $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\operatorname{Re}z>x\}$.

Comment: Why $|\sin(x)|= O(e^{-x})$?  You know that $e^{-x}$ has exponenitial decay.

Comment: My mistake. I suppose that it is correct now.

Comment: You are correct, if we go high up on imaginary axis, the behaviour of two function can diverge. But what if we just consider a box with bound imaginary part, like $\{X+ im, 2X+ im, X- im, 2X- im \}$? 

I think there should be a quatitative version of the identity theorem, I think I am looking for that. Thank you!

Comment: @Sia-TeX That's another question. My goal was to provide an answer to your original question. If you have a new one, then I suggest that you post it as such.